# Что конкретно делает COMMODE.OBJ?

Tags: rtl, c

Либо я туплю, либо гугл мне не хочет искать по такому запросу.

У [майкрософта](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/148505) только общие слова высоким штилем.

Правда ли то, что пишут о нём в [мэйллисте mingw](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnu.mingw.user/28855)?

Comment: Кстати, вот интересный же вопрос, а был заминусован. Кто (на самом деле имя не важно) и **зачем** это сделал ?

Answer (score 2):

Хороший вопрос. Изложу свои предположения.

Интересно некое разночтение между [MinGW-users](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnu.mingw.user/28855) и M$ [документом](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/148505)  по поводу _commit(). IMHO майкрософту надо доверять больше (их система, им виднее). Видимо в **32-бит системе** _commit() на самом деле *не выталкивает данные на диск*, а только "проталкивает" их глубже по кэшам файловой системы. Интересно, что в [Visual Studio 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17618685%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (тоже от M$) про _commit() утверждется - *Flushes a file directly to disk*.
 Как это проверить не знаю.

Тогда что же делает **COMMODE.OBJ** ?

Исходя из изложенного в [документе](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/148505) этот модуль (слинкованный с программой (!)) должен перехватывать **write()** и **_commit()** (скорее всего в нем есть одноименные точки входа) и записывать данные *правильными* (с т.з. синхронной записи (аналогично флагу O_SYNC для *nix open())) вызовами Windows API.

Итак. COMMODE.OBJ, слинкованный с программой обеспечивает прямую запись на диск (аналогично *open(...,**O_SYNC**...)* в *nix) **всех write**(*int fd*) (а следовательно и **fflush**(*FILE **)) программы и корректную работу **_commit**(*int fd*).

Проверить все это не могу, т.к. на моей Win 7 professional 64-bit commode.obj обнаружить не удалось. C _commit() в MinGW программа собирается, а вот делается sync или нет... ?

Если у кого-нибудь еще есть соображения - делитесь. Или у кого есть на компе commode.obj гляньте на него через nm.

Answer (score 2):

Попробую зайти немного с другой стороны, нежели [@avp.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/232/avp)

- Собственно, можно попытаться оттолкнуться от перечисления возможных опций для вариации `fopen` от `Microsoft`. [Одна из них](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/yeby3zcb) - это `commit flag,` который дает следующие гарантии:

> **'c'** - Enable the commit flag for the associated filename so that the contents of the file buffer are written directly to disk if either `fflush` or `_flushall` is called.

- Далее, [документация утверждает](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms235330), что линковка с `commode.obj` равносильна автоматическому проставлению `commit flag` для всех вызовов `fopen.` Как я понимаю, способ выполнения данного контракта является `implementation-specific` вещью.

> - Возникает вопрос - "А как в принципе это можно реализовать на более низком уровне?". Есть парочка идей, которые, в общем-то сводятся к следующему: `if {commode.obj is linked} set_global_commit_flag()`.
> - На практике этого можно также достичь путем переопределения некоторой функции в `commode.obj` и установки всем `.obj'ам,` которые относятся к `Link Options` приоритета в плане резолвинга вопроса `ambigious symbol'ов`.

- Есть еще парочка общих соображений по поводу использования `commit flags` и `commode.obj`:

> - **Don't do that.**
> - Вместо того, чтобы использовать для изменения поведения программы какой-то костыльный `extension` через `obj'и`, на мой взгляд, стоит использовать платформозависимые `WinAPI / open`.
> - `Commit flag` - это действительно `extension.` Подтверждение этого можно найти в документации к `fopen` [на `kernel.org`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/fopen.3.html)

Comment: @Котик, до commit flag в своем исследовании я не дошел. Остановился на предоставленных ТС материалах. 

Вполне реально, что именно так (и имя модуля на эту мысль наводит). 

Хотелось бы на таблицу имен commode.obj поглядеть.